# iOS8 popovercontroller height issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, uipopovercontroller, xcode6

I have a UIPopovercontroller. 
Presenting it using this way.

```
BackupPop *backupPop = [[BackupPop alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
backupPop.delegate = self;

backupPop.navigationItem.title = [Language get2:@"Backup"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:backupPop];
assigningBackupRow = button.tag;
backupPopController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
backupPopController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 150);
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y + 20 + (button.tag - 30000) * 44, button.frame.size.width, button.frame.size.height);
[backupPopController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:backupTable permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

In the UIPopovercontroller, I have a UITableView in viewdidload.

```
funcTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 80) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[funcTable setDelegate:self];
[funcTable setDataSource:self];
[funcTable setRowHeight:44];
[funcTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview:funcTable];
```

The problem in iOS8, although my UITableView is 80px in height, it shows up as 40px only. 
The starting position of the UITableView is right, but the height is not. Now, I have to put 120px as height to all of the UITableView that is in UIPopoverController. No such issue in iOS7. 
Guys, any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

iOS 8 has new PopOverController called UIPopoverPresentationController

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Terms_NC"];

```
 navController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 290);

// Present the view controller using the popover style.
navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:navController animated: YES completion: nil];

// Get the popover presentation controller and configure it.
UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
[navController popoverPresentationController];
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections =0;
presentationController.sourceView = self.view;
presentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 340);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. what i did was i explicitly set the size of tableview again just before i was presenting my popover.

```
[backupPop adjustFrame];
backupPopController.popoverContentSize = backupPop.view.frame.size;
[backupPopController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:backupTable permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

and you can add a method in backupPop

```
- (void)adjustFrame {
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.size.height = 80
    frame.size.width = 200;
    self.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Lemme know if it helps.

Comment: hey thanks for your help, but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

May be its workaround set the content size after little delay.

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 340) animated:YES];
           });